Family get lost and separated on trip
Saw this movie in late 90's/early 2000's. It was about a family - dad, 2 daughters and a son. One of the daughters was in the rebellious teens age and the son was in his early 20's I think. The other daughter was 8-9 years old. 
Anyway, the dad decided to take the family on a shipping/boating trip (or something like that). Then, I think, the boat failed and they got trapped on some small island. The father and son decided to leave the other two daughters and go and look for help; they eventually found help but had forgotten how to get back to the daughters (or actually it might have now been winter time and bad weather was stopping them getting back to their daughters). 
Anyway, 3-4 months past and the weather improved and they made it back to their daughters. 
SPOILER ALERT: I think they then found the daughters and assumed the worse; however, the older daughter kept her sister cuddled up so she saved the younger sister...but can't remember if the older one died. 
Movie was based in Alaska (again, could be wrong)...but the whole ice thing got me thinking it was there.
That's all I have got tbh - I seem to remember it is one of those B-grade movies but had a semi-famous actor in it (although can't remember who he is now!...for some reason I am imagining "Quincy ME" actor playing the dad role!).
Any ideas what this movie was?

Sounds like the plot of Anything to Survive (AKA Almost Too Late) from 1990.

The Barton family; siblings Wendy, Krista and Billy and their father Eddie become stranded on a beach while sailing from Prince Rupert to their home in Ketchikan, Alaska. The plot concerns the family going to extreme lengths to survive after they get stranded on an island in a storm and lose their boat. Billy builds a raft and they attempt to sail to safety but they don't get far. Eddie and Billie head off to seek help while the two daughters try to keep warm under the remains of their boat's sail. Eddie and Billy find their way to a cabin on the mainland but can't raise help. On day 23 they are able to return to the island and find that the girls are alive. Eddie and Wendy have frostbitten feet but all in the family survive and they are able to return to Ketchikan.

Robert Conrad played the dad and a young Matt LeBlanc played the son. Here's the promo:




that's it! Been wanting to find this movie to years! Thanks a lot for that!
